# Как скачать все файлы из папки mail.ru cloud?

Tags: bash, консоль, mail.ru, wget

Есть shell-скрипт, скачивающий файл из облака Mail. Подскажите, как скачивать все имеющиеся в ней файлы в архив zip? Например отсюда https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4oy4/2qQLMMj77

```
#!/bin/bash

# idea: https://novall.net/itnews/bash-skript-dlya-skachivaniya-fajlov-s-mail-ru-cherez-konsol-linux.html

URL="$1"
FILENAME="$2"

[ -z "$FILENAME" ] && {
    echo "Syntax: `basename $0` <url> <dst_path>" >&2
    exit 1
}

URLPART0=$(wget --quiet -O - $URL | grep -o '"weblink_get":\[[^]]\+\]' | sed 's/.*"url":"\([^"]\+\)".*/\1/')
URLPART1=$(echo $URL | awk -F '/public/' '{print $2}')
URLPART2=$(wget --quiet -O - "https://cloud.mail.ru/api/v2/tokens/download" | sed 's/.*"token":"\([^"]\+\)".*/\1/')
wget --no-check-certificate --referer=$URL "$URLPART0/$URLPART1/$FILENAME?key=$URLPART2" -O $FILENAME
```

Comment: Я бы начал с использования *lftp* вместо *wget*... Но если очень хочется, то можно разобрать структуру документа, и уже там найти ссылки, только это на *shell* сделать нельзя (очень трудно). Тем более смотрите, вы используете ссылки на их API, найдите библиотеку для *Python* -- делов-то!

Comment: https://help.mail.ru/top/API/modules

Comment: К сожалению, не обладаю достаточными знаниями для этого.

Comment: Что ж, пожелаю удачи, так как путь, который вы выбрали, гораздо сложнее, чём получить знания и сделать уже всё красиво. Просто для примера, как делается простейший парсер некоего HTML: https://pastebin.com/htRjPBb0

Answer (score 1):

Написал небольшой скрипт на php, который скачивает все файлы из папки облака mail.ru в текущую папку:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$downloader = trim(shell_exec('which aria2c 2> /dev/null'));
$wget = false;
if(empty($downloader)) {
        $wget = true;
        $downloader = trim(shell_exec('which wget'));
}
echo "Using downloader: '{$downloader}'\n";

function downloader($url, $proxy = false, $files = [], $folder = false, $parent = false) {
    global $downloader, $wget;
    if($proxy) {
        $aContext = [
                'http' => [
                    'proxy'           => 'tcp://' . $proxy['server'],
                    'request_fulluri' => true
            ]
        ];

        if(isset($proxy['login']) && isset($proxy['password'])) {
                        $aContext['http']['header'] = 'Proxy-Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($proxy['login'] . ':' . $proxy['password']);
        }
        $cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);
        $html = file_get_contents($url, false, $cxContext);
    } else {
        $html = file_get_contents($url);
    }
    preg_match('/"folders"\:\s+?\{(.*?)\};/s', $html, $data);
    $clean = '{' . stripslashes($data[1]);
    $json = json_decode($clean, true);
    $list = $json['folder']['list'];
    foreach($list as $item) {
        if($item['type'] == 'folder') {
            if(!is_dir($item['name'])) {
                mkdir($item['name']);
            }
            $link = 'https://cloud.mail.ru/public/' . $item['weblink'];
            $files = downloader($link, $proxy, $files, ($parent ? $parent . '/' . $item['name'] : $item['name']), $folder);
        } else {
            if(count($files) > 0) {
                if($proxy) {
                    $html = file_get_contents($url, false, $cxContext);
                } else {
                    $html = file_get_contents($url);
                }
            }
            preg_match('/"weblink_get".*?"url"\:\s\"(.*?)"/s', $html, $weblink_get);
            $dl_server = $weblink_get[1];
            preg_match('/public\/(.*?)$/', $url, $url_path);
            $path = $url_path[1];
            if($proxy) {
                $tokens = file_get_contents('https://cloud.mail.ru/api/v2/tokens/download', false, $cxContext);
            } else {
                $tokens = file_get_contents('https://cloud.mail.ru/api/v2/tokens/download');
            }
            preg_match('/"token"\:"([a-f0-9]+)"/', $tokens, $token_data);
            $token = $token_data[1];
            $dl_url = "{$dl_server}/{$path}/{$item['name']}?key={$token}";
            echo "Downloading file {$item['name']}...\n";
            if($wget) {
                if($proxy) {
                    system("{$downloader} -e https_proxy='http://{$proxy['server']}' --proxy-user='{$proxy['login']}' --proxy-password='{$proxy['password']}' -O '{$folder}/{$item['name']}' '{$dl_url}' &> /dev/tty");
                } else {
                    system("{$downloader} -O '{$folder}/{$item['name']}' '{$dl_url}' &> /dev/tty");
                }
            } else {
                if($proxy) {
                    system("{$downloader} --all-proxy='http://{$proxy['server']}' --all-proxy-user='{$proxy['login']}' --all-proxy-passwd='{$proxy['password']}' -d '" . ($folder ? $folder : '.') . "' -o {$item['name']} '{$dl_url}' &> /dev/tty");
                } else {
                    system("{$downloader} -d '" . ($folder ? $folder : '.') . "' -o {$item['name']} '{$dl_url}' &> /dev/tty");
                }
            }

            if($folder) {
                $files[$folder][] = $item['name'];
            } else {
                $files[] = $item['name'];
            }
        }
    }

    return $files;
}

/* ВАРИАНТ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ БЕЗ ПРОКСИ-СЕРВЕРА */
downloader('LINK'); // LINK заменить на ссылку к папке, например https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4mxD/4mb2WqwUM

/* ВАРИАНТ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ С HTTP ПРОКСИ-СЕРВЕРОМ БЕЗ АВТОРИЗАЦИИ */
downloader('LINK', [ // LINK заменить на ссылку к папке, например https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4mxD/4mb2WqwUM
    'server' => 'PROXY' // PROXY заменить на http-прокси сервер, например 127.0.0.1:8080 или server.com:1234, имя протокола указывать не нужно!!!
]);

/* ВАРИАНТ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ С HTTP ПРОКСИ-СЕРВЕРОМ С АВТОРИЗАЦИЕЙ */
downloader('LINK', [ // LINK заменить на ссылку к папке, например https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4mxD/4mb2WqwUM
    'server' => 'PROXY', // PROXY заменить на http-прокси сервер, например 127.0.0.1:8080 или server.com:1234, имя протокола указывать не нужно!!!
    'login' => 'PROXY_LOGIN', // PROXY_LOGIN заменить на логин для авторизации в прокси
    'password' => 'PROXY_PASSWORD' // PROXY_PASSWORD заменить на пароль для авторизации в прокси
]);

echo "Done! :-)\n";

echo "\n";
```

Примеры работы с ним есть в самом скрипте.
Требования к системе: любая операционная система linux с установленным php и aria2 или wget (для скачивания файлов).

Comment: Что-то пошло не так. ./mail.sh https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2pzd/4a1EExvvb/ Using downloader: '/usr/bin/wget' PHP Warning: file_get_contents(LINK): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/scripts/mail.sh on line 27 PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /opt/scripts/mail.sh on line 30 PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/scripts/mail.sh on line 33 PHP Warning: file_get_contents(LINK): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/scripts/mail.sh on line 25 PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /opt/scripts/mail.sh on line 30 PHP Warning: Invalid arg